# Is this proof that $f(x) \in X$ valid?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

I just finished this question from my exercises for Foundations and Proof.

The problem states;

Let $ X = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \neq 1\} $. Define $ f:X \to X$ by $f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x-1}$

For $x \in X$, show that $f(x)$ is indeed an element of $X$.

My proof is as follows;

For $f(x)$ to not be in $X$, $f(x)=1$, as there does not exist $x\in X$ so that $\frac{x+1}{x-1} = 1$, $f(x)\in X$

Is this proof correct, or is it not thorough enough?

Comment: I would say, not thorough enough.  You should explain why $\frac{x-1}{x+1}=1$ has no solutions.

Comment: You might state _why_ there does not exist $x \in X$ such that $\frac{x+1}{x-1} = 1$. "This would imply that $x+1 = x-1$ which implies $1=-1$..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. You might consider flushing out a little more detail to verify that $\frac{x+1}{x-1} \neq 1$. The contradiction wouldn't be too hard, namely that $$\frac{x+1}{x-1} = 1 \\ \implies 1=-1$$

Comment: Ok! I did think about doing that, but instead I showed 0 = 2, which didn't seem as neat to me as yours

Comment: @J_mie6 yeah, $0=2$ isn't a good enough contradiction for this proof ;) How did you get $0=2$ though? I can't get to that contradiction.

Comment: $x+1 = x-1 \to x-x = 1 + 1 \to 0 = 2$

Comment: Ah. That works too!

Answer (score 1):

I would suppose that the instructor might want you to prove that $\not \exists x: x \neq 1 \wedge \frac{x+1}{x-1} = 1$.

This is easy:  If $\frac{x+1}{x-1} = 1$ multiply both sides by $x-1$ to get
$x+1 = x-1$ and such an $x$ does not exist.